# JQuery and Dynamic javascript execute

Tags: jquery

Suppose one line or few lines of javascript is assigned to a variable. How could I execute it by jQuery.

Suppose `alert($("#txtName").val());`

The above code is assigned to a variable then how could I execute it by jQuery at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `eval` function. Example:

```
var someCommand = 'alert($("#txtName").val());';
eval(someCommand);
```